# Data Structure for Saving Username/Password in a Client/Server Java Application

Tags: java, sockets, data-structures

I'm currently getting into Socket Programming and building a multi-threaded console application where I need to register/login users. The data needs to be saved locally, but I can not seem find the right structure for it.

Here are the ideas I though about:

- Simply saving the data to .txt file. (will be troublesome to search and authenticate the logins)
- Using the Java Preferences API but since the application is multi-threaded I keep on overwriting the data each time a new client connects to my server. Can I create a new node for each new user?

What do you guys think is the ideal structure for saving login credentials? (security isn't currently a concern for this application)

Comment: You want to be careful about "security isn't currently a concern for this application". Also, is using a DB an option? That might be the cleanest way to store data. Lastly, at least hash your passwords...

Comment: It's a simple learning application that will run on the localhost so that's why I am not focusing on securing it. I was looking for a structure that's simpler than a database just to save the credentials.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider the H2 database engine.

quote:"Very fast, open source, JDBC API Embedded and server modes; in-memory
   databases Browser based Console application Small footprint: around 2
   MB jar file size"

http://www.h2database.com

Comment: You need to be careful. h2 doesn't always support concurrency.

Comment: H2 adds a lot of overhead which might not be required for that use case. It's a suitable option when switching between e.g. MySQL in production and a faster in-memory solution but for a plain simple application, this adds a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you want to do with the application. The result would be different, depending on what you would answer to the following questions:

- Do you want/need to persist the databases?
- Is there any other data which you need to store along with that?
- are you using plain java or a framework like Spring?

Some options:

- if you're just prototyping and you don't have any persistence: consider using an in-memory storage for it. For simplicity in coding/dependencies, something like a `ConcurrentMap` can be completely sufficient. If you wrap it properly, you can exchange it later - and you don't add dependencies and complexities at an early state.
- If you're prototyping but you still need persistence, using properties files on top of the ConcurrentMaps can give you a quick win.

There might be some more stages to this, depending on where you want to go with this, choosing a database at one point can be an option. Depending on your experience and needs, you can use a SQL or NoSQL database. Personally, I get faster results with NoSQL (MongoDB in my case) but prefer SQL in production for use cases like account management.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer! For simplicity I don't want to use a database; I'm writing plain java console program and the login credentials is the only data I'm storing. I think the second option of using properties files on top of ConcurrentMaps would be perfect as the login information will need to be preserved each time the server is terminated.